# fetch not returning data in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new to react, i'm having difficulty getting data for a single book out of  list, be passed through via axios' get method.
I think it has something to do with the url, but I have been unable to get fix it.

Here's my code:

```js
export function loadBook(book){
    return dispatch  => {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/books/book/:id').then(book => {
            dispatch(loadBookSuccess(book.data));
            console.log('through!');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error');
        });
    };
}

//also tried this
export function loadBook(id){
    return dispatch  => {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/books/book/' + {id}).then(book => {
            dispatch(loadBookSuccess(book.data));
            console.log('through!');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error');
        });
    };
}
```

Html code that contains a variable link to each individual book

```html
 <div className="container">
                <h3><Link to={'/book/' + book._id}> {book.title}</Link></h3>
                <h5>Author: {book.author.first_name + ' ' + book.author.family_name}</h5>
                <h4>Summary: {book.summary}</h4>
                <BookGenre genre={genre} />
                              
            </div>
```

link in Route:

```html
<Route path="/book/:id" component={BookPage} />
```

Edit: code for the book component

```js
class BookPage extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const book = this.props;
        const genre = book.genre;
        console.log(book);

        return(
            <div>
            <div>
                <h3> {book.title}</h3>
                <h5>Author: {book.author.first_name + ' ' + book.author.family_name}</h5>
                <h4>Summary: {book.summary}</h4>
                <BookGenre genre={genre} />                
            </div>
        
        </div>
        );
    }
}

BookPage.propTypes = {
    book: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

//setting the book with mapStateToProps
function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps){
    let book = {title: '', author: '', summary: '', isbn: '', genre: []};
    const bookid = ownProps.params._id;
    if(state.books.length > 0){
        book = Object.assign({}, state.books.find(book => book.id));
    }
    return {
        book: book
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(loadBook, dispatch)
    };
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookPage);
```

Comment: Firstly check if this api is working 'http://localhost:3000/api/books/book/' + {id} fine.Next from where are u calling the function loadBook() and are u passing the id properly.

Comment: what is that id,is that a object or just a string,if its a string no need to use curly braces.

Comment: @pritesh, the api is working. Tested it using postman. The action loadBook() acts as both the api call and the redux thunk.  This is the route it is supposed to call: ***router.get('/books/book/:id', book.book_detail);***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution to this problem.
My mistake was that I failed to send the id of the item I along with the api call.
Using componentDidMount and sending the dynamic id from the url params solved this problem for me.

Thank you, @Vinit Raj, I guess I was too much of a rookie then.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out by my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this:-

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/books/book/' + {id})
```

You should do like this:-

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/books/book/${id}`)
```

So your **action.js** might look like this:-

```
export function loadBook(id){
    const request = axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/books/book/${id}`);
    return dispatch  => {
        request.then(book => {
            dispatch(loadBookSuccess(book.data));
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error');
        })
    };
}
```

Since the id, you have passed it seems to be a string so it can be concatenated using **ES6 template strings** and make sure you wrap your strings in backtick . or you can do it by `+` operator, also make sure you pass `id` as a parameter in your `loadbook` function so that you can join it to your URL.

Comment: @Nnanyielugo It was my mistake i have updated the answer please recheck it and tell me if something is wrong

Comment: Still nothing. Console logs this *** GET /api/books/book/undefined****. And on chrome debugger, loadBook(id) shows 'undefined', and doesn't even get passed on to the reducer.

Comment: are you able to console.log the id in loadbook function,and please specify where you have called this action creator

Comment: The action creator is in the same file as the thunk that makes the api call. this is the action creator     ***export function loadBookSuccess(book){
    return {type: types.LOAD_BOOK_SUCCESS, book};  //create corresponding handler in reducers file
}***